# Facebook Likebox display post by Language (fan page using target/language)

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

I have a multilingual fan page so I use either the function Target/Language or the Location/Language (when I click on the "public" button to select who I want to share my post with) so that my fans only see the post in their language.

So here is the thing : when I share something, I have to post 2 posts : one in English and one in French. But my fans only see the one in their language.

The problem is that LikeBox retrieves all my posts in FR and in EN so it's kind of redundant. I would like to find a way to only select the post in French for my French website and only the one in English for my English website.

Any idea if it's possible? And if yes, what should I do?

Thanks a lot for your help!